# Выборка записей по дате sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть таблица в БД которая содержит набор неких записей, одно из полей строки этой таблицы имеет тип текст и содержит дату в таком формате:

```
SimpleDateFormat dataFromat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");               
cvHeader.put(dbConnector.ORDER_DATE,dataFromat.format(currentDate));
```

Теперь хочу выбрать данные из этой таблицы. Логика такая, в активити есть поле с выбором даты, когда пользователь её выбирает, то в переменные заносятся значения для года, месяца и дня соответственно, вот пример:

```
private static Date changeCalendarDay(int daysCount, int field) {
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(year,month,day);
    calendar.add(field,daysCount);
    year = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Этот метод дергается когда пользователь увеличивает или уменьшает текущую дату на 1.
Так вот, пользователь поменял дату, в переменные записались значения, после этого вызывается метод которая делает выборку данных из базы и выводит результат в лог. Но я не могу выбрать записи из базы, делаю вот так:

```
dbConnector dbConnector = new dbConnector(getContext(),BasicSettings.Main_DB_Name,BasicSettings.Current_DB_Version);
db = dbConnector.getWritableDatabase();
String targetDate = "'"+year + "-"+(month)+"-"+day+"'";
Cursor cursor = db.query(BasicSettings.OrderHeaders_DB_Table, dbConnector.ALL_ORDER_HEADERS_COLS_LIST, dbConnector.ORDER_DATE + "=?", new String[]{targetDate}, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.d("ORDERSINFO",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.ORDER_CODE)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Но записей не находит... Можно ли как-то сделать выборку, чтобы не переиначивать способ хранения даты в базе? Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз вы решили хранить дату как строку в формате "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", так и ищите по ней соответственно.
Простым сравнением тут не обойтись, т.к. от пользователя вы получаете только саму дату, а в БД это записано как дата-время. Поэтому ничего и не находит.

Чтобы все работало, используйте оператор `LIKE`, запрос должен иметь условие такое:

```
WHERE ORDER_DATE LIKE '2017-08-30%'
```

Получите все записи с датой, начинающейся с такой строки, т.е. определенного дня.

Тут есть туториал: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Comment: Спасибо! Вот так всегда, застрял на самом очевидном)

Answer (score 1):

Selection вида `dbConnector.ORDER_DATE + "=?"`
будет искать полное совпадение строк. Так как у Вас дата хранится в формате 
`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (с часами, секундами и миллисекундами), то строку вида

```
 String targetDate = "'"+year + "-"+(month)+"-"+day+"'";
```

данный select не находит.

Один из вариантов решения проблемы - использовать SQL оператор LIKE:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(BasicSettings.OrderHeaders_DB_Table, dbConnector.ALL_ORDER_HEADERS_COLS_LIST, dbConnector.ORDER_DATE + " LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + targetDate + "%"}, null, null, null);
```

[Подробнее про оператор LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)